# Where is customer firstname, lastname stored in magento 1 table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-account

Could you let me know where is customer firstname and lastname being stored in magento 1 database table ?

I didn't seem to find them in customer_address_entity or customer_entity.

I wanted to select all customers from my database whose total characters in name is greater than 15

Answer (score 0):

> check this table **customer_entity_varchar**

Answer (score 0):

Customer firstname and lastname is stored in customer_entity table.
Checkout below link of install schema of customer_entity table for magento 1.0.0-beta6 version.

[Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallSchema](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1.0.0-beta6/app/code/Magento/Customer/Setup/InstallSchema.php#L105)

Comment: Question was for M1

Comment: I have updated the answer.